# Im getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, undefined

I have created this project, using React-Vite for the frontend and Node for the backend. Working in local mode everyrhing works fine, but when i enter the Vercel deployed version I´m getting this error and the web will not load.

The funny thing is that i'm only getting this error when using Chrome and from my laptop. If i use Edge to access the url everything goes well, and also if I use Chrome in my mobile phone.
The whole error message goes like this:
ypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
at $J (index-3741cc67.js:321:32421)
at ab (index-3741cc67.js:38:19538)
at Jg (index-3741cc67.js:40:3139)
at CL (index-3741cc67.js:40:44830)
at xL (index-3741cc67.js:40:39787)
at D5 (index-3741cc67.js:40:39715)
at mh (index-3741cc67.js:40:39568)
at c0 (index-3741cc67.js:40:35933)
at tS (index-3741cc67.js:40:36737)
at Aa (index-3741cc67.js:38:3279)

Any idea why this could be happening?
Thanks in advance!

I haven´t tried anything so far, as i'm not getting any clue from the error message as where the problem comes from.
ChatGPT has not helped lol

Comment: have you tried to clear every thing , like cookies and all  ? 
and try chrome in incognito mode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was in this function:

```
 const { isFavorite, handleFavorites, showFavorite } = useFavorites(
    user?.favorites.includes(evento._id) || false,
    evento ? evento._id : null,
    user ? user._id : null
  );
```

As soon as I added question marks to favorites and evento, the error dissapeared:

```
 const { isFavorite, handleFavorites, showFavorite } = useFavorites(
    user?.favorites?.includes(evento?._id) || false,
    evento ? evento._id : null,
    user ? user._id : null
  );
```